# match two dataframe columns, return different column value

Tags: python, dataframe

This should be simple, but can't seem to find it.

dfA # list of names of students(500 students in my list) - shortened to just first name

| ID | Cola |
| --- | --- |
| 00 | None |
| 01 | Mike |
| 02 | Sue |
| 03 | Tom |

dfB # UID is the class subject(in another df)(34 separate class subjects)(normally 20 students to each class)

| UID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 01 | 02 | 03 |
| 02 | 02 | 03 | 00 |

### expected output

dfB

| UID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Mike | Sue | Tom |
| 02 | Sue | Tom | None |

I am really new to Dataframe manipulation like this in python.
I have looked at map, mask, query and nothing seems to fit,
because of different header names.

Someone requested the actual code and this is what I have got:

```
...
    dcol1 = [14, 12, 18, 28, 107, 303, 421]  
    dcol2 = [15, 12, 17, 29, 108, 305, 421]  
    colh = ['UID', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6']  
    dfA = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(colh))  
    dfA.loc[0] = dcol1  
    dfA.loc[1] = dcol2  
    print(dfA)
    ncol1 = [12, 17, 18, 29, 107, 108, 303, 305, 421]  
    ncol2 = ["Mike", "Tom", "Sue", "Carol", "John", "Sam", "Tim",   "Linda", "Jim"]  
    dfB = pd.DataFrame({'NID':ncol1, 'Name':ncol2})  
    print(dfB)  
    # replace number ids with names  
    dfB = dfB.applymap(lambda i: dfA.iloc[i]['Name'])  
    print(dfB)  
...
```

As you can I see, I really simplified it it the basics.

Comment: Could you put your input and output dataframe in the form of pandas DataFrame code or output? This looks pretty confusing

Comment: It was in the code box, but lost formatting when in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EDIT

*Based on the exchanges in comments*

I updated the provided code (you inverted dfA and dfB compared to your example above, the NID 28 was missing in dfA and I set the correct columns as indexes) and it works just fine for me now.

```py
import pandas as pd

ncol1 = [12, 17, 18, 28, 29, 107, 108, 303, 305, 421]  
ncol2 = ["Mike", "Tom", "Sue", "ADDED 28", "Carol", "John", "Sam", "Tim",   "Linda", "Jim"]  
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'NID':ncol1, 'Name':ncol2})  
dfA = dfA.set_index('NID')
print('dfA', dfA) 

dcol1 = [14, 12, 18, 28, 107, 303, 421]  
dcol2 = [15, 12, 17, 29, 108, 305, 421]  
colh = ['UID', 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5', 'id6']  
dfB = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(colh))  
dfB.loc[0] = dcol1  
dfB.loc[1] = dcol2  
dfB = dfB.set_index('UID')
print('Intial dfB', dfB)

# replace number ids with names  
dfB = dfB.applymap(lambda i: dfA.loc[i]['Name'])  
print('Final dfB', dfB)
```

---

### Initial solution

*Not so natural when there are many columns in dfB.*

Not so easy without the formatting in the question but have you tried something along the lines of

```py
dfB.join(dfA, on='ID1', rsuffix='1') \
   .join(dfA, on='ID2', rsuffix='2') \
   .join(dfA, on='ID3', rsuffix='3')
```

and then keep the columns you need from the final dataframe (`COLA1, COLA2, COLA3` in your case).

Comment: Quite long if number of columns are larger than 20, like in a classroom.

Comment: What about `applymap` then? Like `dfB.applymap(lambda i: dfA.loc[i]['Cola'])`. You can also convert dfA to a Series before with `matches = dfA['Cola']` and then do `dfB.applymap(lambda i: matches.loc[i])` which may be a bit more efficient / lighter

Comment: UID column causes key error(key) from  err on both.

Comment: key error(key) seems to be caused by i not accessing past the fourth iteration. The actual dataframes are over 500 rows of students with nearly 34 class subjects, and this method stops after first 35 students

Comment: Dumb question but are you use all the ID appearing in dfB are in the index of dfA? Can you paste the error you get?

Comment: raise KeyError(key) from err, keyerror 35 - notice the number is above 34, happens to all students numbers above 34, YES all ID in dfB are in dfA

Comment: A few more questions: are the first columns of your dataset above the indexes or just the first columns? Because .loc uses the index. Also could it be a type problem? The ID seem to be strings (for 00 to work) could the erroring 35 be an int and cause the issue?

Comment: If it still doesn’t fix it, can you paste your current code and I’ll try to make it work on my side with dummy data.

Comment: The first columns are the ids of the class subject not indexes. dfB are all numbers and data type is integer (maybe should be converted to string??)

Comment: For my solution above to work, they need to be indexes not another column. And I guess you could try converting everything to string to see if the error is still there.

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if that helps

Comment: Yes, I missed the reversal and missing data, The solution is quite good. It allows me to do more than the few columns provided and at the same time is quite simple while being understandable. The set_index seems to be the major item.

Comment: Great! Happy it's clear and useful :) Good luck with the rest of the work!

Comment: noticed slight problem with rerunning code, set_index has problems if you don't first reset index -- example dfA = dfA.reset_index().set_index('colA')